# Entity Framework code first migrations for context with entities added dynamically

Tags: entity-framework

I have a data context where I discover entities during run time. In my `OnModelCreating` method, I loop through all sub classes of `EntityTypeConfiguration<>` and add them to `DbModelBuilder`.

After enabling migrations for this context, if I call `Add-Migration` to create an initial migration, I get empty Up and Down methods.

When adding entities to `DbContext` during run time, is there way to use `Add-Migration` so that it automatically generates migration code or do I have to manually write required migration code?

It looks like I need to figure out a way to pass in required list of `EntityTypeConfiguration` when `Add-Migration` calls parameter less constructors.

Here is code

```
 public class GenericSQLDBContext: DbContext
 {
    protected List<Type> _dataMapTypes;

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    #region OnModelCreating
    /// <summary>
    /// This method loads all the *Map files in the assembly
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (_dataMapTypes != null && _dataMapTypes.Count > 0)
        {
            var typesToRegister = _dataMapTypes.Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
            .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
            foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
            {
                dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
            }
        }
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    } 

    public GenericSQLDBContext(List<Type> listOfMaps) : base()
    {
        _dataMapTypes = listOfMaps;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sharing some code may help

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is being generated is because you're likely not defining your `DbSet<TEntity>` properties...

example...

```
public class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public ExampleContext() : base("ExampleDbConnection"){}

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

I haven't tested the code above just wrote it on the fly here... but it should work... See that property of type `DbSet` there, that's what you're likely missing... Can't really say more without seeing your code though

Comment: I do have a DbSet property but it is a generic. something along the lines of "IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()". I have it this way so that I dont have to change my context as I add new models.

Comment: But... you do need to change your context.... If your site was a blog, you have to have concrete models defined like this... `public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get;set; }     public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; } ` If you don't have them set out, then you're leaving nothing to generate, in addition, the modelBuilder is supposed to be supplied with an object that derives from `EntityConfiguration`, this object typically has very specific configuration settings for a particular entity

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but EF isn't designed for this... even if you succeeded there's no point, you would have a database with a single table, regardless of your navigation properties on that entity...

Answer (score 0):

You can do auto migration at run-time

```
var config = new DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext> { AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true }; 
var migrator = new DbMigrator(config); 
migrator.Update();
```

For more details about dynamically building model at run-time in entity framework take a look at this link:
http://dynamicef.codeplex.com/